# How to parseIPv6 address in a string using Python 3.x

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, ipv6

I'm trying to find out IPv6 address from a string. I've done this on IPv4 part by using `re.findall(re.compile('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'),addr)`. How can I modify this to IPv6?

Here's my string:

```
addr = "......IP address is 2001:0000:3238:DFE1:63::FEFB. SUbnet mask is.........."
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mnordhoff/2213179

Comment: Depending on your purpose, you might be interested in the [`ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#module-ipaddress) which is part of the stdlib in python 3.3+ and also [backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress) for previous python versions.

Comment: as @marty suggested use ipaddress module .

Comment: Are you trying to validate if a given string is an IpAdresse or do you have a long string which might include an IpAdresse?

Comment: @user1767754 I have a long string which include IP Address and words.

Comment: Is the IP always surrounded by the same text?

Comment: Nope. FYI, I had successfully parse out IPv4 address from mystring by using `re.findall(re.compile('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'), addr)`

Comment: Yeah the question is, can one string contain multiple matches? Ipv6 is way more complicated than IPv4

Comment: It might be multiple matches.